# Подсчёт количества пользователей и количества заказов

Tags: sql

Есть таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача отобразить такой результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помочь не просто вывести юзер - кол-во, а именно количество юзеров с совпадающим количеством заказов.
На скриншоте видно, что два пользователя(userId = 3 и 1) сделали по 4 заказа.

Comment: Ну обычная вложенная группировка. Внутри считаешь количество заказов, снаружи количество количеств.

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. Спам тегами удалён.

Comment: За спам тэгами прошу прощения. СУБД - MySQL.

Comment: Ну и какие сложности? не можете сразу - выполните хотя бы первый шаг и посчитайте количество заказов для каждого отдельного клиента. PS. A где версия MySQL? не вижу...

Comment: С этим проблем не возникло вообще, тут вроде все предельно понятно: SELECT count(userId)
from ORDERS
group by count(userId)

Comment: Ну вот теперь представь что результат этого запроса - отдельная таблица... скажем, order_amount. Сможешь написать запрос, который выдаст нужный ответ?

Comment: Я только изучаю язык SQL,  делаю это через сторонний сайт(пишу запросы), поэтому версию не поскажу. Ищу решение без использования оконных функций,  до них мне ище далеко. Застопорился на этом: SELECT count(student_id) as test, 1 as counter
FROM attempt 
GROUP BY student_id
Тестирую код на схожей таблице, поэтому названия столбцов не совпадают. Мне бы хотелось понять могу я как то еще раз схлопнуть то, что у меня получилось при написании кода выше, по идее еще одна группировка по первому столбцу и я получу тот, результат, который требуется.

Comment: *версию не поскажу* неужели так сложно выполнить `SELECT VERSION();` и показать ответ? *делаю это через сторонний сайт* какой именно?

Comment: 8.0.27, stepik: Интерактивный тренажер по sql

Comment: Почти наверняка это MySQL. Проверь запросом `SELECT @@version, @@version_comment;`

Comment: *тут вроде все предельно понятно* Что вернёт этот запрос? Думаю, что ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: 8.0.27    | MySQL Community Server - GPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот так, например...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       COUNT(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) `пользователей`,
       COUNT(*) `заказов`
FROM orders
GROUP BY userid;
```

Только чему ты на таком ответе научишься?

---

Решение без использования оконных функций, расписано по шагам.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WHWzn90y)

Comment: Огромная вам благодарность за выдержку и такое подробое описание. Не знал, что так легко можно ссылаться на промежуточную таблицу, arigato :)

Comment: @UchuMatChast Не ссылаться. Во время составления запроса я её создал, конечно, но в финальном запросе она не используется - т.е. если её удалить, всё одно получим нужный результат. https://dbfiddle.uk/Bcag7pbA